# Error in running an external exe wrapped inside my winforms aspnet

Tags: c#, php, winforms

I created a winforms application that does nothing but just run an exe which i have included it in my project and i created a setup project and added the project output option and checked the option copy localised resources. Then i built my setup project in release mode and installed the setup file. Everything was successfull till now. When i start my app it should start the exe that i have included inside it (wrapped in setup files(setup project)) on FORM_LOAD. The exe does its part correctly the external exe starts up but it suddenly crashes displaying php error.
My external exe is the php webapplication exe created using exeoutput software. So what im trying to do is to wrap this phpexe inside my winforms to create an installer for this phpexe. When i run the phpwebapplicationexe from my local folder it runs smoothly but when i run my winforms app and when implicitly the phpexe runs it shows some php error..
I'll include my screenshots here.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace POSApplication
{
public partial class Default : Form
{
    public Default()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Default_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            string AppPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "POS_MAIN/pos.exe");
            Process.Start(@AppPath);
            this.Close();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

}

[[SCREEN_SHOT] The phpexe created from exe output that i am including in my project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J6MKu.png)

[[SCREEN_SHOT] My setup project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Dt08.png)

[[SCREEN_SHOT] The error that i get after running my winforms exe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MnEqh.png)

[[SCREEN_SHOT] When i run the external phpexe from my local folder it runs successfully](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pZ5sg.png)

Comment: Please put code and output as text into the question, not as screenshots.

Comment: ok but its just a one line code of process.start method.. so only i put the screenshot

Comment: Please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: i have included the code above @Garriet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
string path="path/to/executable.exe"
string arguments_list_as_string="--argument1 value1 --argument2 value1"
var p=new ProcessStartInfo(path);
p.Arguments=aruguments_list_as_string;
try
{
   Process.Start(p);
}catch(Exception e)
{
   MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
}
```

you can put the executable in build output directory and do set path to

```
 string path=System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location+"\\executable_name.exe";
```